# spring3 - change the action method

Tags: java, forms, spring, annotations

On Spring with annotations, is there anyway that i can change the form action without changing the action using javascript?

For example on submit1 method invoked on the controller = method1

on submit2 method invoked on the controller = method2

```
@RequestMapping("/submit1")
public String submit1()

@RequestMapping("/submit2")
public String submit2()
```

...

```
<form:form id="dynamicfrm" method="post" action="archive/submit.do" commandName="submit">
 <input type="submit1" value="">
 <input type="submit2" value="">
```

Thank you!

Comment: It isn't terribly clear what you're asking, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - as others already said it isn't absolutely clear - than you want to map one single form to different action methods dependending on the button that was clicked.

In your JSP you can change the code to something like this:

```
<form action="/submit.do" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="show">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
</form>
```

And in your controller you can narrow the mappings like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", params="action=show")
public String showEntity() { /* ... */ }

@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", params="action=edit")
public String editEntity() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @user648026 Oh, nothing to be sorry for. In my opinion asking questions like this is far away from asking newbie questions. You were in search for a better solution, you were not happy with the dirty approach you already knew about.